# Conditional Summations

Tags: summation, wolfram-alpha-queries

I am not a math major, but for a networking class, I am taking I am required to do summations for probability. I know the logic but I don't know the mathematical theory to make this work. Using Wolfram I'm trying to do this

```
sum [(35 choose n)* (100*j)*(.1^n* .9^(35-n))] from n=0 to 35, if[n>10, j=10, j=n]
```

Essentially, what I'm asking is: How do I run a summation with a variable that is affected by an `if` statement in this way? Or is there a different math I should be using.

Edit: Sorry for not being clear. I am trying to do this in Wolfram Alpha. I did not realize there was a difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions concerning Wolfram|Alpha are specifically excluded from this site

Comment: Okay, I am sorry. I did not realize

Answer (score 6):

```
Sum[Binomial[35, n]*100*If[n > 10, 10, n]*(.1^n*.9^(35 - n)), {n, 0, 35}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm used to programming, I couldn't fully grasp how the `if` statements worked. I tried looking here but was confused by all the high level stuff. This is perfect. Thank you so much

edit: Wolfram didn't understand

Answer (score 3):

```
Sum[Binomial[35,n]100*Min[10,n]*.1^n*.9^(35-n), {n,0,35}]
```

> 349.946

Nested `If` statements work well in *Mathematica*, but Wolfram|Alpha seems to have some issues with them. However, in this case using `Min` to grab the minimum of `n` and `10` achieves the appropriate behavior.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly. That reads "minimum n, maximum 10"?

Comment: `Min[10,n]` is "the smaller of 10 and n". Or, "n, but no more than 10".

Answer (score 3):

You can also get `Expectation` of transformed random variable `y = 100 Min[10, x]` where `x` is a random variable with distribution `BinomialDistribution[35, .1]`:

```
Expectation[100 Min[10, x], Distributed[x, BinomialDistribution[35, .1]]]
```

> 349.94631523961846

Alternatively,

```
td = TransformedDistribution[100 Min[10, x], Distributed[x,BinomialDistribution[35, .1]]];
Expectation[y, Distributed[y, td]]
```

> 349.94631523961846

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
Sum[Binomial[35,n]100 j .1^n .9^(35-n)/.{j:>10/;n>10,j:>n/;n<=10},{n,0,35}]
```

> 349.946

Comment: I can't get this to work in Wolfram Alpha either. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to evaluate this sum using Wolfram|Alpha and not Wolfram _Mathematica_, I would edit your post to make that explicitly clear (though I can see where the confusion comes from).

Comment: Okay, I will. Sorry, I thought they used the same code. That's why I tagged it Wolfram-alpha-queries. I'm new to this